# Events of Properties View in my own eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I implemented a Properties View in my own editor in eclipse and I start this view using the code:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("org.eclipse.ui.views.PropertySheet");
```

1) Are there listeners that are fired when properties view became visible or invisible, gain ou lost focus?

2) What code I use to know if properties view is closed?

3) What code I use to know if the properties view is opened but not visible? Like this image:

Figure 1

[image: Figure 1]

4) How can I know if it is visible and have focus? Like image:

Figure 2

[image: Figure 2]

5) And if it is visible and DONT have focus, like:

Figure 3

[image: Figure 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IPartListener2` to listen for all part events.

```
IPartService partService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService();

partService.addPartListener(listener);
```

You will get events for all parts so you will have to check the event is for your part. The listener gets events for all the state changes of a part (open, closed, activated, brought to top, ....)

There is also a very similar `IPartListener` but `IPartListener2` should be used if possible.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your answer. The problem is when the "Properties View" lost focus and became deactivated. I can't know if the view is visible or not. For example, in Figure 1 of example 3 and Figure 3 of example 5, the function partDeactivated was executed. But on the code I cant know if the view still visible or not.

Comment: You get `partVisible` and `partHidden` events, you will have to track these.

Comment: IPartListener2 have partVisible and partHidden and it worked. Thank you.